# Google Analytics Transactions Ids with Session Ids in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with Google Analytics data in BigQuery and trying to combine Sessions Ids with Transaction IDs. I am facing some difficulties as I do not understand yet how to combin Session Ids (to match with GA UI I've used `totals.visits = 1` in WHERE clause) with Transactions IDs (`UNNEST(hits)`). Condition: Data should match with the GA UI.

**Desired outcome**

*Date | Session ID | Transaction ID*
2019-06-18 00:00:00.000 UTC | 400101010101 | AAAAAAA
2019-06-18 00:00:00.000 UTC | 400202010102 |    BBBBBBB
 2019-06-18 00:00:00.000 UTC | 400303010103 | CCCCCC

**Current query to retrieve Timestamp and SessionIds**

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date)) AS Date,
CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING) ) AS SessionID 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING) )) AS Sessions, /* verify match with GA UI*/
FROM
`ga-xxxxx.yyyyyyyy_sessions_20*`
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX = '180618'
AND totals.visits = 1
GROUP BY
1,2
```

**Current query expended with TransactionID**

When expending the query with `hits.transaction.transactionId` and `UNNEST(hits)` I get more records than in GA UI. Seems like the query is counting the SessionIDs plus TransactionIDs.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date)) AS Date,
CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING) ) AS SessionID, 
hits.transaction.transactionId AS transactionId, 
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId, CAST(visitId AS STRING) )) AS Sessions, /* verify match with GA UI*/
FROM
`ga-xxxxx.yyyyyyyy_sessions_20*`,                                  
 UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX = '180618'
AND totals.visits = 1
GROUP BY
1,2,3
```

How can I get `SessionID` and `hits.transaction.transactionId` into the query with the condition that the data match with GA UI?

Hope somebody can help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To match the count of sessions in the GA UI back to BigQuery you can count sessions like this:

`CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS sessions`

Then, if you want to see a session ID along with the transaction ID, you could do something like:

```
    SELECT Date,
    CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS visit_ref,
    hits.transaction.transactionID AS transaction_id
    FROM `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_20180619`
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
    WHERE hits.transaction.transactionID IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Date, visit_ref, transaction_id
```

Note that I have removed any sessions that did not transact in the above, but you could remove this `WHERE` clause if you want them there.

If you are getting more rows using this method then consider that you may have sessions where a user places more than one order, you could get some insight into this by using `STRING_AGG` to list all transaction ID's next to a session ID, in the example below I've also counted them and sorted by this count:

```
   SELECT Date,
   CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitId AS STRING)) AS visit_ref,
   STRING_AGG(hits.transaction.transactionID) AS transaction_id, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId) AS orders
   FROM `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_20180619`
     CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
   WHERE hits.transaction.transactionID IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY Date, visit_ref
   ORDER BY orders DESC
```